# How can I get the cid of the latest comment I saved using comment_save?

Tags: nodes, comments

This is my code to programmatically save comment:

```
  $comment = (object) array(
    'nid' => $loaded_node->nid,
    'cid' => 0,
    'pid' => 0,
    'uid' => $loaded_node->uid,
    'mail' => $account->mail,
    'thread' => '00/',
    'created' => $loaded_node->created,
    'changed' => $loaded_node->created,
    'is_anonymous' => 0,
    'homepage' => '',
    'status' => COMMENT_PUBLISHED,
    'subject' => $comment_body_subject,
    'language' => $node_language,
    'comment_body' => array(
      $node_language => array(
        0 => array (
          'value' => $comment_body_value,
          'format' => 'msg_filtered_html',
        )
      )
    ),
  );


  comment_submit($comment);
  comment_save($comment);
```

I want to get the cid of comment just saved. How can I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `comment_save()` is using [`drupal_write_record()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7), and [cid is the primary key for the comment table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.install/function/comment_schema/7), the value of `$comment->cid` is updated after the call to `comment_save()`.

Answer (score 3):

The cid value should be in the comment object after it has been saved. So you should simply be able to use something like this:

```
comment_save($comment);
drupal_set_mesage("ID is " . $comment->cid);
```